# Javascript set const variable inside of a try block

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, try-catch

Is it possible in **ES6** to set a variable inside of a `try{}` using `const` in strict mode?

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');

try {
    const configPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), config);
} catch(error) {
    //.....
}

console.log(configPath);
```

This fails to lint because `configPath` is defined out of scope. The only way this seems to work is by doing:

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');

let configPath;
try {
    configPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), config);
} catch(error) {
    //.....   
}

console.log(configPath);
```

Basically, is there any way to use `const` instead of `let` for this case?

Comment: What do you expect to happen with `console.log(configPath);` if an error is thrown?

Comment: Not the only way. `var` is still exist. so use `var` inside the `try{}catch(){}`

Comment: @FelixKling In that situation I expect `configPath === undefined`.

Comment: It would be great if there was an inline try-catch expression or if try block could return a value to the outer scope. `const value = try path.resolve() : undefined` or `const value = try { ... } catch(e) { .. }`.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Declaring a variable as `const` requires you to immediately point it to a value and this reference cannot be changed.

Meaning you cannot define it at one place (outside of `try`) and assign it a value somewhere else (inside of `try`).

```js
const test; // Syntax Error
try {
  test = 5; 
} catch(err) {}
```

On the other hand, both creating it and giving it a value within the `try` block is fine.

```js
try {
  const test = 5; // this is fine
} catch(err) {}
```

However, `const` is block-scoped, like `let`, so if you do create it and give it a value within your `try` block, it will only exist within that scope.

```js
try {
  const test = 5; // this is fine
} catch(err) {}
console.log(test); // test doesn't exist here
```

Therefore, if you need to access this variable outside of the `try`, you must use `let`:

```
let configPath;
try {
   configPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), config);
} catch(error) {
    //.....   
}

console.log(configPath);
```

Alternatively, although probably more confusingly, you can use `var` to create a variable within the `try` and use it outside of it because `var` is scoped within the function, not the block (and gets [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)):

```
try {
   var configPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), config);
} catch(error) {
    //.....   
}

console.log(configPath);
```

Comment: Is using var in this instance frowned upon, and should we always try to use let and const now? Or is var still ok for these kinds of use cases?

Comment: @hamncheez the main issue with using `var` in this manner is that it introduces an additional cognitive overhead to the programmer. Such a situation makes it difficult to easily tell all the portions of the scope that this `var` is leaking into since it is actually global to the function (even though it is defined within a smaller block). This is particularly an issue in bigger functions or perhaps functions where similar (or same) variable names are used; `var` inherently requires more thinking to comprehend its behavior and is thus more prone to lead to bugs.

Comment: I like the last method using `var`. However I'd always put `configPath = undefined;` in the catch block. Especially when the block is inside a loop, to avoid it to have the value from a previous iteration.

Comment: Both the `let` & `var` case will result in a typescript error: `Variable 'configPath' is used before being assigned. ts(2454)`

Answer (score 36):

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');

const configPath = (function() {
  try {
    return path.resolve(process.cwd(), config);
  } catch (error) {
    //.....
  }
})()

console.log(configPath);
```

Comment: If you're using ramda.js, the tryCatch function provides an abstraction of this. See https://ramdajs.com/docs/#tryCatch

Comment: That's so close to supporting a monadic approach to try/catch.

Comment: Nice use of IIFEs I liked this approach!

Comment: I'd recommend using arrow anonymous function, so that `this` is the same as in the outer context

Answer (score 4):

I would try to use a temp variable with `let` and assign that to a `const` var after the `try`/`catch` and 'delete' the temp var.

```
'use strict';

let temp;
try {
  temp = path.resolve(process.cwd(), config);
} catch (error) {
  //.....   
}

const configPath = temp;
temp = undefined;

console.log(configPath);
```

Comment: I am not sure if using this or a function to assign the value is the way to go. This can be risky if you work with objects and forget to reset the temp. For instance:

let temp = {a: 2};
const notemp = temp;
temp.b = 3;

will make booth temp and notemp into {a: 2, b:3}

Comment: Why not use `delete temp`?

Comment: @Zer0 because in JavaScript the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator "has nothing to do with directly freeing memory". It "removes a given property from an object". And `temp` is initialized to a string primitive that isn't a [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/property/JavaScript) of an object. And [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), "unlike `var`, does not create a property on the global object". So `temp` doesn't refer to a property of an object.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the try block altogether if the function is async! Just learned this today, thought I'd share!

More broadly applicable to just your situation as this is the top Google result for "const in a try block"

```
'use strict';
const path = require('path');

const getPath = async () => {
    return path.resolve(process.cwd())
}

const logPath = async () => {
    const configPath = await getPath().catch(e => console.log(e)) <--avoid the try
    console.log(configPath);
}

logPath()
```

Works great when you're already in an async function and need to wait for something else:

```
async function main() {
  const result = await asyncTask().catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

Learned from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55024396/2936521

Comment: Bear in mind that whatever is returned from the .catch will be assigned to the result. In both these examples the result will get a value of undefined (as discussed in the comments of the answer you linked).

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of good answers here. But it's real annoying to have to manage your lets being inside and out of scope. So if you are like me, and came here searching for a better pattern. I wrote a little utility that helps a ton.

```
export const tc = <T>(option: { try: () => T; catch: (e: Error) => T }) => {
  try {
    return option.try()
  } catch (e) {
    return option.catch(e)
  }
}
```

Here are some unit tests to show how it's useful

```
import { tc } from './tc'
describe('tc', () => {
  it('should return successfully', () => {
    const result = tc({
      try: () => 1 + 2,
      catch: () => -1,
    })
    expect(result).toEqual(3)
  })
  it('should catch', () => {
    const spy = jest.fn()
    const result = tc({
      try: (): number => {
        throw new Error('Test')
      },
      catch: (e) => {
        spy()
        expect(e.message).toEqual('Test')
        return -1
      },
    })
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(result)
  })
  it('should rethrow', () => {
    expect(() =>
      tc({
        try: (): number => {
          throw new Error('Test')
        },
        catch: (e) => {
          throw e
        },
      }),
    ).toThrowError()
  })
  it('should have proper types', () => {
    // @ts-expect-error
    const result: string = tc({
      try: () => 12,
      catch: (e) => {
        return -1
      },
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the `let` options I see here, another option may be to use an object, as the reference to the object is constant, but it's properties can be altered, so something like this:

```js
'use strict';

const path = require('path');

const configPath = { value: null };

try {
    configPath.value = path.resolve(process.cwd(), config);
} catch(error) {
    //.....
}

console.log(configPath.value);
```

It would probably be cleaner to stick with let, but I just wanted to point out another possible option.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```js
  const result = await promise.catch(err=>{
    console.log(err)
  })
```

Answer (score -3):

**Use `let`.** You cannot use `const`. `const` does not allow you to reassign the declared constant. While it is generally good practice to declare objects like yours with `const`, the *entire point of doing so* is to allow objects to be mutated without allowing them to be reassigned. You are reassigning the object (thus, defeating the purpose of `const`), so use `let` instead.

```
let path = require('path');
// Good to go!
```