# how use const in try catch block

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, ecmascript-6

const is a block level variable so when i try suspect code

```
try{
   const foo = bar[global.name].foofoo[global.name2];
}catch (err){
    console.log(error(err.message));
}
```

const is hide in the `{}`

but

```
const foo ;
try{
    foo = bar[global.name].foofoo[global.name2];
}catch (err){
    console.log(error(err.message));
}
```

not working either because `const` must be init on declaration.
So how should I using `const` in `try..catch` block ?

**Edit 2024**
solution:  I can just use `var` and the problem solved

Comment: `const foo = (() => { try { return ...} catch(e) { return defaultValue})()`

Comment: In this case you can declare a variable with `let` rather than `const`, outside of your try/catch block

Comment: Please show us what you were trying to do with `foo` and where - if you don't need it, the solution is to omit it

Comment: This is a fundamental question. for sure I have other solution to make code work. but I wonder what Ecma thinks when they implement/design this

Comment: They think that when you declare `const` inside a block, you will only use it inside that block. If you wanted to use it outside of the block, that would raise the question what its value would be if the block is not executed (e.g.  when an exception happens and only the `catch` block is executed). If you cannot answer that question, `const` is not what you want.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50870635/476951

Answer (score 44):

You've hit the nail on the head, because of block scoping you can't declare a `const` in a try catch block and use it outside the block.

You have <s>2</s> 3 options:

**Use `let`:**

```
let foo;
try{
    foo = bar[global.name].foofoo[global.name2];
}catch (err){
    console.log(error(err.message));
}
```

Or if there is very little code to come after the try catch block, *and* it all depends on the success of the `try`, you can **put the rest of the code in the `try`**:

```
try{
    const foo = bar[global.name].foofoo[global.name2];
    return foo;
}catch (err){
    console.log(error(err.message));
}
```

**EDIT**

Option 3 inspired by @Yury Tarabanko's comment: if possible **modularise the try catch part into its own function**, the output of which should be the value of the new `const`:

```
function trycatch() {
    try {
        return bar[global.name].foofoo[global.name2];
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(error(err.message));
        return undefined; // or whatever you want
    }
}

const foo = trycatch(); // === bar[global.name]... if succeeded, otherwise === the return value from the catch block
```

Comment: There is option #4 based on #1 described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50870635/476951

Comment: I like option 3, but it cannot be used if you must stop the initial function in the catch.

Comment: I came here looking for better solutions, but I guess there aren't any.  Currently using your first solution, except assigning the `let` value to a `const` after the block.  Unfortunately, I can't delete the temporary variable to let the runtime know it can optimise it away, as far as I know.

Comment: There's an alternative to option 3 here which I think is an improvement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40925094/javascript-set-const-variable-inside-of-a-try-block/50870635#answer-65209114