# TypeScript: How to set a const variable in a try block?

Tags: typescript, error-handling

I want to declare a `const` variable, initialize it inside a `try` block, and then use it outside of that try block. For example:

```
const result;

try {
    result = getResult();
} catch (error) {
    report(error);
    return;
}

use(result);
```

Or asynchronously:

```
const result;

try {
    result = await fetchResult();
} catch (error) {
    report(error);
    return;
}

use(result);
```

What I don't want:

- Use `let` because that allows overwriting the `result` later on.
- Move this to a separate function because I only want this logic to be accessible inside the given scope.

I'm seeing this pattern a lot in my code, so is there any way to do this using a modular TypeScript solution?

The following questions are similar, but don't provide a reusable type-safe solution:

- [how use const in try catch block](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43090614/4136777)
- [Javascript set const variable inside of a try block](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40925094/4136777)

Comment: If an error is thrown, the code below the `catch` is never used. Why not just put the subsequent code *inside* the `try`?

Comment: @crashmstr Because the code below the `catch` could also throw, and that might require different error handling. So putting everything inside the same `try` block could lead to unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Synchronous solution

Use the following type-safe utility function:

```
function tryGet<T>(getter: () => T): {
    success: true;
    value: T;
} | {
    success: false;
    error: Error;
} {
    try {
        return {
            success: true,
            value: getter(),
        };
    } catch (error) {
        return {
            success: false,
            error: error as Error,
        };
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
import { report, use } from './imagination';

const result = tryGet(getValue);

if (!result.success) {
    report(result.error);
    return;
}

use(result.value);
```

### Asynchronous solution

```
export default async function tryGetAsync<T>(
    getter: () => Promise<T>
): Promise<{
    success: true;
    result: T;
} | {
    success: false;
    error: Error;
}> {
    try {
        return {
            success: true,
            result: await getter(),
        };
    } catch (error) {
        return {
            success: false,
            error: error as Error,
        };
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
import { report, use } from './imagination';

const result = await tryGetAsync(fetchValue);

if (!result.success) {
    report(result.error);
    return;
}

use(result.value);
```